# Fragment and Activities

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

Hello I am creating an application in Android using Tab Layout. I am not good with fragments and I cant get it to work, the application displays the right layout but button and stuff like that is unresponsive. Here is my code (I cant make the first class "FragmentActivity" because the caller wont accept that

```
public class ebookC extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {



    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_ebook, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


    }


    public static class ebookr extends FragmentActivity {
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.layout_ebook);
            Button button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextbt);
            final TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pageCount);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView.setText("Works????");
                }
            });

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't have a FragmentActivity extended class inside a Fragment extended class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the activity ebookr is actually not used. I'm also guessing that the fragment does get used, but you expect the OnClickListener to work.
Here is what I assume you are trying to do:

```
public class ebookC extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_ebook, container, false);
        Button button= (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.nextbt);
        final TextView textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.pageCount);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    textView.setText("Works????");
                }
            });
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```